# How do I convert arrays from Verilog to VHDL?

Tags: verilog, vhdl

I came across this register instantiation in a Verilog code and would like to convert this to VHDL. I understand the conversion of Instantiation 1*, but I am stuck at Instantiation 2.
*Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Instantiation 1:**

Verilog:

```
reg [4:0] temp_seed [8:0];
```

VHDL:

```
type temp_seed_type (8 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal temp_seed : temp_seed_type;
```

**Instantiation 2:**

Verilog

```
reg [23:0] ola [4:0] [4:0];
```

Comment: Type temp_seed_type isn't a two dimensional array type, instead it is single dimensional array type with an element type that is itself a single dimensional array type.There are two syntax errors in the declaration of type temp_array_type which serve to invite a valid [mcve]. It's also a single dimensional array type, temp_array_type having only one index while also supplying the unconstrained array element type with an index constraint (It's an array of array elements).

Answer (score 2):

You can add more dimensions in the parentheses:

```vhdl
type ola_type is array(4 downto 0, 4 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);
signal ola : ola_type;
```

Reading the standard or a good beginner's book helps. ;-)

Comment: While this is possible, I find arrays of arrays more practical, as slicing can be performed. So using `type temp_seed_array_type (4 downto 0) of temp_seed_type` might be more preferable. In addition, if you use VHDL 2008, you can use unconstrained arrays. `type temp_seed_type (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(natural range <>);` and then set the size when creating the object, created many fewer type conversions.

Comment: The OP's question's single dimensional array VHDL example claimed to be a *two-dimension array* and instead having a single index and an element type (a single dimensional array type, See e.g. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 "An array object is characterized by the number of indices (the dimensionality of the array)"; ...) also has two missing reserved words from the type declaration, errors perpetuated in this answer. The usefulness of the question and answer to future readers is in question and upvoting alone isn't curative. Fix the syntax.